# Connected App Using Server To Server JWT OAuth Can Only Have One Session At A Time

Tags: api, oauth2, connected-apps, session, jwt

I have a connected app that I authenticate to from multiple servers using the same IP in my data center. (This Salesforce org is setup to only allow IPs in the allowlist - which ours is in.) The first server to authenticate using "OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Flow for Server-to-Server Integration" is successful. After that every server that tries to authenticate using the same user and credentials fails with the error message `user hasn't approved this consumer`.

The user has the same profile as the connected app and the app is set to "admin approved users are pre-authorized". The org uses API Access Control, but the app is installed and unblocked. On the user page the login history says "Failed: Not approved". This confuses me as per my understanding the user having the same profile as the connected app *is* approval. Also, it does work once - so, that seems to indicate that it is approved.

If we revoke the session from the admin UI, we can login again, but again only once.

I was wondering if maybe this org has a limit on the number of sessions a single user can have with the app at once. Or maybe a limit on sessions per IP. If so, where would that setting be and could it be changed?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.